# After printing a range I'm getting 100+ instances. Is there a way how many numbers were printed in that range before break?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range(1000):
    my_ticket = random.randint(1, 1000)
    if my_ticket % 100 == 0:
        break
    else:
        print(my_ticket)
```

I am trying Lottery Analysis problem included in the Eric Matthes book "Python crash course". I am trying to find out the probability of me getting the number

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator is already tracking how many, the break ends the loop so all you have to do is literally print `i` immediately prior.

```
    if my_ticket % 100 == 0:
    print(i)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter variable `c` before the `forloop`.

Everytime it goes to else it will increase by 1

```
import random
c=0
for i in range(1000):
    my_ticket = random.randint(1, 1000)
    if my_ticket % 100 == 0:
        break
    else:
        c+=1
        print(my_ticket)
print("Total numbers printed: ", c)
```